# Read and Write to Java file via Resource

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to read and write to a file but I'd like to access that file via Resource.

This is what I do

```
File f = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/blah/blah/Properties.prop").toURI());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
String line = br.readLine();

PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/blah/blah/Properties.prop").toURI()));
```

but neither seems correct. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For input, try below:

```
     InputStreamReader isReader = 
                      new InputStreamReader(
                          this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(templateName));
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isReader);
```

or

```
     InputStreamReader isReader = 
                      new InputStreamReader(
                          <youclassName>.class.getResourceAsStream(templateName));
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isReader);
```

For output, try below:

```
      PrintWriter writer = 
               new PrintWriter(
                     new File(this.getClass().getResource(templateName).getPath()));
```

Comment: Should work same way, but don't read and write the same file at same time.

Comment: can you show me code. I can't seem to get the PrintWriter working

Comment: Sorry I missed. `getResourceAsStream` is always input stream. Updated the answer for PrintWriter, please try. By the way, did reader work?

Comment: It should be mentioned that there may not be a file that can be written to. If the resource is part of a `.jar` file, writing will fail. (Even if you could modify the jar file, it could be signed or simply not be located on the machine running the jvm...)

Answer (score 3):

All solution above show how you can receive access to your resources in **build folder**. It means that resources have been moved to build directory with **.class** files.
If you need to write some files into resources for saving them after terminated program, then you will have to describe path starting with root project:

> ./src/main/resources/foo.ext

This solving generally not recommended but may be necessary in other cases.

Comment: I was asking by myself if there is a way after pointing to target folder to swich in the original resouce path.

Answer (score 1):

More simply,

```
 try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(Resources.getResource("path").toURI()))) {
        //bufferedReader...
    }
    try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(Resources.getResource("path").toURI()))) {
        //bufferedWriter...
    }
```

Note that the path is relative to the resources folder.

Comment: This solution doesn't appear to work when the resource is embedded within a jar file. In my case the resource's URI evaluates to `"jar:file:/C:/PCProxAPI/PCProxAPI.jar!/com/agilysys/rguest/buy/peripherals/PCProxPlusConfig.cfg"` and `Paths.get(...)` throws `java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException`

Comment: For anyone else who is wondering that `Resources` class is actually `com.google.common.io.Resources`

Comment: @HairOfTheDog, "Paths" utility only "knows" the file system. Once a file is packaged in the jar, it's no more a file system paradigm.

Comment: @HairOfTheDog: We can think to smthg like : 
Files.streamToString(Resources.getResource("foo/bar.txt").openStream());
It will work even if the file is packaged (exception was thrown by Paths.get method)

Comment: I tried this but it does not create the outputstream in Resources folder but in target folder.